# Bootstrap Tab Flyout Menu with Hover

Tags: javascript, tabs, hover, twitter-bootstrap, flyout

Im trying to create a Flyout Menu where the 2nd level is a big div where the user can do stuff. Think of it as a product page. You have 3 products and the flyout presents features and info on the product. At the bottom there could be a DownloadNow-Button or something.

So the flyout has to be visible when either hovering over the corresponding tab button or the flyout itself. It should be automatically invisible at any other time.

It has to be done with the Bootstrap-Tab plugin.

Rough jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QPfWb/2/

Aaand now im stuck. The flyout should disappear when not hovering over button or flyout itself.
I tried some mouseLeave functions but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try .mouseout() like my example http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/Mf4Vh/